# "Programming Pearls": conflicting types for qsort

Tags: c, xcode, qsort, programming-pearls

This is the solution of *Programming Pearls* in column 1.6_1:

```
> #include <stdio.h>

int intcomp(int *x, int *y)
{
    return *x-*y;
}
int a[1000000];
int main(void) {
    // insert code here...
    int i,n=0;
    while (scanf("%d",&a[n])!=EOF) {
        n++;
    }
    qsort(a,n,sizeof(a[0]),intcomp);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

> conflicting types for "qsort"

Can you tell me why could that happen? Isn't it defined by default?

My compiler is **Xcode** (MacOS).

Comment: It's unclear if the source code above was from typed in from the book, or found online.  The code above has a few differences from this [github copy of p1c1quicksort](https://github.com/McBadger/ppearls/blob/master/part-1/column-1/qsortints.c), i.e. the code above is missing `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: The code is typed from the book , but the book's code doesn't have any code about header file.So I add this one, but I missed another one like the code you gave.It worked .Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment (which turned out to be a correct guess) promoted to answer:

It's unclear if the source code above was from typed in from the book, or found online. The code above has a few differences from [this github copy of p1c1quicksort](https://github.com/McBadger/ppearls/blob/master/part-1/column-1/qsortints.c), i.e. the code above is missing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>.
```

Comment: thanks you but I'm sorry that I can't vote for your because of the low reputation.

Comment: @zyMacro, reputation is not needed to to mark a question "answered", click the *hollow* check mark to the left of the answer so it turns *green*, at which time you'll get **+2 rep**.  For more detail, see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).